# case statement inside where clause sql server

Tags: sql-server, case

I want to put a case condition inside where clause,ie if `semester column` of second table is null,i need to filter the columns where `semester is null`. If not,I need to filter the data on another condition.

//**if semester is null,I need the query to be like this:**

```
select * from tbl_courses tc
    left join tbl_exams te on tc.courseID = te.courseID
    where te.gradeID=10 and 
    te.semester is null
```

//**if semester is not null,query should be**

```
select * from tbl_courses tc
left join tbl_exams te on tc.courseID = te.courseID
where te.gradeID=10 and 
te.semester is null
```

For this requirement how can I write a single query from sql itself like the following:

```
select * from tbl_courses tc
left join tbl_exams te on tc.courseID = te.courseID
where te.gradeID=10 and 
(case when te.semester is null 
  then te.semester is null
  else te.semester = tc.semester END)
```

Any way this is not right.Please help me

Comment: Can you specify what you want? I don't get it right away. But I'm sure I can provide you a simple answer.

Comment: @Ionic  
If te.semester is null ,I need to select the data where te.semester is null.If it is not null,I need to select data where te.semester = tc.semester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your second select statement should be:

```
select * from tbl_courses tc
left join tbl_exams te on tc.courseID = te.courseID
where te.gradeID=10 
and te.semester = tc.semester
```

Try this:

```
select * 
from tbl_courses tc
left join tbl_exams te on tc.courseID = te.courseID
where te.gradeID=10 
and (
     te.semester = tc.semester
     OR te.semester is null
)
```

Comment: If te.semester is null ,I need to select the data where te.semester is null.If it is not null,I need to select data where te.semester = tc.semester. @Zohar Peled